Request for Schematic Review: ESP32-D0WD-V3 Minimum Functionality Check
I’ve been working on a custom PCB design using the ESP32-D0WD-V3, and I’d appreciate a second pair of eyes to ensure everything is on track for the minimum functionality of the board. The current schematic includes essential components such as the power supply (3.3V), decoupling capacitors, strapping pins, memory flash (W25Q64JV), and proper connections for the crystal and reset circuits. I'm not using RF, so the LNA_IN pin is terminated with a 49.9Ω resistor.
I’m aware that a few components are still missing from the schematic, such as the USB-to-serial converter for firmware downloads, GPIO headers, and some other peripherals, but I want to make sure the core functionality is solid before moving forward.
Could anyone take a look and provide feedback on whether everything appears correct for basic operation? I’ve followed the Espressif hardware guidelines as closely as possible, but an extra check would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!.


The answer to question "could someone take a look" is yes, someone could. Can you please ask a specific question, as any open-ended question can have any answer. Especially schematic review requests. I could say you are missing a power led and by some metric I could have the most correct answer, even if it is useless.

@Justme My question, which was aimed at verifying whether the schematic meets the minimum requirements for operation according to the guidelines, should be quite clear in context. The focus is not on aesthetic additions like a power LED, but rather on ensuring that the components and circuits as shown in the schematic are correctly connected and meet the necessary technical standards for functionality. I would appreciate feedback that sticks to the schematic provided, evaluating whether the components and circuits align with the requirements laid out in the relevant guidelines.
